# mysqldump does not dump (empty SQL file)

Tags: mysql

I ran the command

mysqldump -h MYHOST -u MYUSER -p MYDATABASE > MYSQLFILE.sql

but it generated SQL file with several comments only. No any data or DDL inside.

No any error message also.

**SQL file is following**

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.13, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: MYHOST    Database: MYDATABASE
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.6.32

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Comment: Then it seems that you selected the wrong database

Comment: What does it mean "wrong"?

Comment: With the above command, you selected "MYDATABASE" as database. Maybe you have an other one, with nearly the same name or the data you are looking for is in a different database.